# How to break sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a table named **sequence** with a single column **val** and table looks like

```
val
-----
1
2
3
5
8
9
10
```

i need to identify the range of numbers if there is a break in sequence and output like

```
range_start    range_end
-----------    ----------
1              3
5              5
8              10
```

Comment: I have *guessed* this is Oracle based on your Title. Please don't just add random RDBMS tags to your questions, it only confuses matters; it actually makes people less inclined to answer your question as they don't know what RDBMS you are *really* using,.

Comment: Take a look at this Q and A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658675/min-and-max-values-grouping-by-consecutive-ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract an increasing sequence and you'll get a constant for values that are in sequence.  Then aggregate:

```
select min(val), max(val)
from (select val, row_number() over (order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (val - seqnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG()` function to assign a group by number to each value. Then grouping is easy.

For example:

```
with
a as (
  select val,
    case when lag(val) over(order by val) = val - 1 then 0 else 1 end as adjacent
  from sequence
),
b as (
  select val,
  sum(adjacent) over(order by val) as grp
  from a
)
select min(val) as range_start, max(val) as range_end 
from b 
group by grp
```

Result:

```
RANGE_START  RANGE_END
-----------  ---------
1            3        
5            5        
8            10
```

For reference, the data script I used is:

```
create table sequence (val number(6));

insert into sequence (val) values (1);
insert into sequence (val) values (2);
insert into sequence (val) values (3);
insert into sequence (val) values (5);
insert into sequence (val) values (8);
insert into sequence (val) values (9);
insert into sequence (val) values (10);
```

**Side Note**: `sequence` is a really bad name for a table. Some tools may get confused by it. Sometimes you'll be forced to enclose it in double quotes all around the place.